# Explanation of Gradle Jar task manifest configuration

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am looking at the following Gradle snippet:

```
apply plugin: java

task customJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes firstKey: 'firstValue', secondKey: 'secondValue'
    }
}
```

If I understand this correctly:

1. The `manifest` snippet will call a `manifest(Closure<?>)` method in the `Jar` task,
2. `Manifest` object is passed to the closure
3. `attributes` snippet will call the `attributes(Map)` method on the `Manifest` ?
4. The `firstKey: 'firstValue', secondKey: 'secondValue'` will create a `Map`? It looks like the map literal need to be part of [].

Comment: Are you sure there's a colon after `attributes`?  That looks wrong.  Also, what's the question?

Comment: Sorry, the output was somehow chopped.

Comment: Your understanding is good, what's the problem?

Comment: The map syntax is not the same as described in the Groovy documentation. + I was not sure if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Your understanding seems fine, and that's a perfectly valid way of passing a map to a function

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking The map syntax for arguments does seem to be described in the Groovy documentation: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_named_arguments

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the Map literals. Thanks to all of you. Please add comments and I can at least vote for you.